# How to save save data from dyanamic combobox to excel cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a form which added combo box dynamically. Now i want to save this data back to excel cells with updated value.
Here is my code to add combobx to forms

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 30
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
Dim theLabel As Object
Dim labelCounter As Long
    Set theLabel = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", Cells(i, 1).Value, True)
    With theLabel
        .Caption = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Left = 5
        .Width = 200
        .Top = 20 * i
    End With
    Dim DesiredControl As Control

Set DesiredControl = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", Visible)
DesiredControl.Left = 350
DesiredControl.RowSource = "Interface!xfd2:xfd150"
DesiredControl.Top = 20 * i
DesiredControl.Width = 175
DesiredControl.Height = 19
'DesiredControl.AutoComplete = enable
Next i
End Sub
```

Every thing is fine till now

now i want to save each combo box value to excel cells.
for that i tried it as

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim irow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Interface")
Sheets("Interface").Range("B1").value = UserForm1.ComboBox.1.Value

End Sub
```

But i didn't get success. Please correct me.

Note each combo box add dynamically in forms.

Comment: Strange syntax: `Userform1.ComboBox.1.Value1`, why do you have ".1" after ComboBox? And what excacly id your problem? It does not work as you want - something happens, some error appears?

Comment: i added .1 just because when we add dynamic combo box it mention over there.. so think it should be use as it is.   please correct me

Comment: Oh... it's ComboBox within Excel sheet, right? Overlooked that. Anyway please clarify your problem.

Comment: i am looking for the code that save my each drop down combo box data to at range sheets("Interface").range("B1:B10") when i click on save button.

Comment: Hope its clear to you.. thanks for respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the control when you add it:

```
Set DesiredControl = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "Combo" & i, Visible)
```

and then refer to it using the controls collection:

```
Sheets("Interface").Range("B1").Value = UserForm1.Controls("Combo1").Value
```

for example.

Comment: Perfect!!.. Its works   Thanks for valuable response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim irow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Interface")
Sheets("Interface").Range("B1").value = UserForm1.ComboBox.ListIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: i Tried it  but It gives me compiler error "method or data member not found" at combobox